# RDS Database backup to S3 using Azure Pipeline, Error SQL Powershell Module is not installed on your agent machine,

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3, azure-pipelines, amazon-rds, devops

I am facing the error in the title while running the Azure release Pipeline. SQL Server Database Deploy task is getting failed. In the task, I am taking the RDS database backup using following command.

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database 
        @source_db_name=@SRC_DB_NAME, 
        @s3_arn_to_backup_to=@BACKUP_FILE_ARN,
        @overwrite_S3_backup_file=1,
        @type='full';
```

SQL Powershell Module is already installed in the agent machine and "vstsagent" service is restarted after the installation. Not sure how to proceed further. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which agent are you using, hosted or private? And Have you updated your agent in the agent pool? Go to the "Agent pools" tab, open the shortcut menu for the pool of your build agent and select "Update All Agents": https://github.com/geeklearningio/gl-vsts-tasks-azure/wiki/How-to-Install-SQLPS-on-your-Build-Agent

Comment: I am new to this. I am sorry if i am not understanding your question. My deployment group having a server, which is driving the database release to AWS. I have registered the agent in that server by running the Registration script (PowerShell). SQL Powershell module is also installed in that server. How can i update the agent in the Agent pool and make the changes you suggested? Can you please guide me?

Comment: I am using Deployment Group with multiple servers separated by tags. With this setup, will the changes you suggested work? If yes, could you please guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue with the following steps.

1. Installed "Microsoft SQL Server Feature Pack" in the Agent machine
2. Restarted the agent service
3. "Update Targets" in the Deployment Group under the Pipelines in the azure portal

I hope this will be helpful for someone else.